# Prolog - Print all EVEN numbers from 1 to 10

Tags: prolog

I am trying to print all even numbers from 1 to 10 using Prolog and this is my code

```
printn(10):- write(10).
printn(X):- (X mod 2 =:= 0 -> write(X), Next is X+1, nl, printn(Next)).
```

but it prints me "false" when i write the following query:

```
?- printn(1).
```

Comment: You need an "else" clause.

Comment: `between(1, 10, X), X mod 2 =:= 0, write(X), nl, fail; true.`